# Can webapp in virtual machine access a cache role in azure?

Tags: .net, azure

the question is very simple. I've got a website deployed on azure's virtual machine, also there's a dedicated cache role deployed on cloud service. The question is, how can I make the website in virtual machine access the dedicated cache role? Please someone give me some instructions to go or advice some good articles.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Currently the only viable solution is accessing Caching from the same cloud service (same Role or another Role). The question is why are you using VM to deploy a web application in Azure?

Comment: because vm give me more space to install external softwares like 7zip, so my webapp can utilize them to do some file processing

Comment: Small Instance of Cloud Service gives you 200GB space to install third party apps, is that not enough for a Web application ?!

Comment: actually I dont't know what's the difference between a vm and an in-role vm?

Comment: Web Role / Worker Role are *stateless* Windows Server VMs (they get created in the same initial clean state when you scale), and then you install your software via startup scripts at bootup. Unless you have Linux requirement, manual-install processes, or very lengthy installs, Web Role (or worker role if using an alternative web server like apache) is your best bet & will give you access to dedicated cache role. More info [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/).

Answer (score 1):

It's some kind of a 'hack' and i didn't actually test it:

You can add an `Endpoint` to the Cache role and then obtain the list of IP addresses the role is bound to using something like:

```
var cacheRole = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.Roles["Cache"];
var cacheEndPoints = cacheRole.Instances.SelectMany(x => x.InstanceEndpoints).Where(x => x.Key == "CacheEndpoint").ToList();
```

The above code assumes that you explicitly added an Endpoint (named `CacheEndpoint`) to the Cache role (named `Cache`). it also assume that you have another role as part of the same deployment of the cache role that is able to actually invoke the above code and return the results.

Alternatively, you can use the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) (easier using the [Service Management Library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.Library/)) to obtain the Cache Endpoint (even from within the VM role which is not part of the same deployment as the cache role).

Then you'll have to configure the client code accordingly (Session State / Output Cache adapter for example):

```
var cacheConfig = new Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
cacheConfig.AutoDiscoverProperty = new DataCacheAutoDiscoverProperty(false);
cacheConfig.Servers = cacheEndPoints.Select(x => new DataCacheServerEndpoint(x.Value.IPEndpoint.Address.ToString(), x.Value.IPEndpoint.Port));
```